# Specific Array Index and calling method java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Hello i have some questions regarding methods. So i have written down the code whereby users key-in the temperature from January to December, and it will print out which month has the maximum temperature and the value of the temperature.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    final int size = 12;
    String[] month = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December" };
    double[] temp = new double[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter temperature on first day of " + month[i]);
        temp[i] = sc.nextDouble();

    }
    int maxIndex = maxV(temp);
    System.out.print("Highest temperature in " + month[maxIndex] + " with a temperature of " + temp[maxIndex]);
}

public static int maxV(double temp[]) {
    double maxVL = temp[0];
    int indexM = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        if (temp[i] > maxVL) {
            maxVL = temp[i];
            indexM = i;
        }
    }
    return indexM;
}
```

So this is my code, i don't understand how does month[maxIndex] work is it because i return the highest index of the month? isn't it supposed to be maV(temp)? and as for the temperature value too how could temp[maxIndex] work?

Comment: Check out the [Java Tutorial on Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). May wanna check out the other articles they have on the [Java basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html).

Comment: Your code looks correct; it iterates over the array of temperatures, and then returns the _index_ of the slot with the highest temperature.  In your `main()` method, you then use this index to print out the name of the month and its highest temperature.  What is your question?

Comment: You could certainly improve your code, but if there are no errors, then what is the question?

Comment: i don't really get the part of array[method]

Comment: when i used maxV(temp) for the value instead of temp[maxIndex] i got logic error why is that so?

Comment: That's because those are two different constructs. `temp[maxIndex]` accesses the value at an index (see the array tutorial). In this case, it `temp[maxIndex]` returns the highest temp, which is based on your input (for example, it could be 100). `maxV(temp)` is a method that returns the index for the highest temp (which won't be higher than 19).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of,
System.out.print("Highest temperature in " + month[maxIndex] + " with a temperature of " + temp[maxIndex]);

You can use, 
System.out.print("Highest temperature in " + month[maxV(temp)] + " with a temperature of " + temp[maxV(temp)]);

Even here you will loose the decimal value of the temperature, But i think this will clear your doubt.

Comment: yeah i did that buy i still don't really understand the temp[maxV(temp)] because it returns my highest index it also return my highest temperature?

Comment: @rhezapaleva The `maxV(temp)` executes first, which returns the index containing the highest temp: if `temp` consists of `20, 100, 90`, then `maxV(temp)` would return `1`. That value (`1`) is then used to access a value in the `temp` array. That's how [expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html) work. I highly recommend you read the tutorials.

Comment: @rhezaPaleva Both the arrays have 12 values starting from index 0 to 11. For example your 7th index of temperature array is of highest temperature then it is obvious that the index is same in month array aswell.(i.e.,7 August)

Answer (score 0):

In `maxV(temp)` method you actually passing array of temperatures for each month (month determined by the index of temp[] array) then returning the index of maximum temperature value of `temp[]` array which is `maxIndex`.

`month[maxIndex]` -> will return the month which has the maximum temperature value.

`temp[maxIndex]`  -> will return the value of maximum temperature in that month.

**Example:**

```
month = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December" }

temp = {22, 20, 35, 15, 20, 22, 26, 30, 18, 27, 20, 19}
```

If max index `i = 2` then the month will be the third `month[2] = "March"`.

The temperature of `"March"` : `temp[2] = 35`.